# Split a list multiple time in Prolog

Tags: prolog

this my code :

```
 div2(L,N,L1,L2) :-
  length(L1,N),%n=4
  append(L1,L2, L),
  L=L2,L1=[],L2=[].
```

i want it to display each time in L1 a 4 element list but it return false.
example :

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
L1=[1,2,3,4]
L1=[5,6,7,8]
L1=[9,10,11,12]
L1=[13,14,15,16]
```

how can i make it work. and thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean you want `L2=[5,6,7,8]`?  And you want `L1` to be the first 4 elements of `L`, with `L2` being the rest?

Comment: What is `N` used for?  In your current code, it doesn't seem to be used for anything.

Comment: Scott Hunter yes., i edited,

Comment: Two answers were given. Was neither one acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `div(L,N,L1,L2)` to be that `L1` is the first `N` element of `L`, and `L2` is what remains:

```
div2(L,N,L1,L2) :-
    length(L1,N),
    append(L1,L2,L).
```

There are no other conditions that need to be placed on `L`, `L1` or `L2`.

If you want to be the first 4 elements *after some multiple of 4* elements, and `L2` to be the rest, you need to say so:

```
div2(L,N,L1,L2) :-
    append(L01,L2,L), % break up L
    length(L01,Nx),   % make sure prefix's length is multiple of N
    0 is mod(Nx,N),
    append(L0,L1,L01),% set L1 to be last N elements of prefix
    length(L1,N).
```

Comment: yes but that will do it just one time. i want it to repeat the process until the end of L. and thank you for replying

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution...

```
div2([X|Xs], N, P) :-
    (   length(P1, N),
        append(P1, R, [X|Xs])
    ->  (   P = P1
        ;   div2(R, N, P)
        )
    ;   P = [X|Xs]
    ).
```

This solution defines a list `P1` of length `N`, and attempts to unify it (with `append` as a prefix list of `[X|Xs]`. (`[X|Xs]` is used instead of `L` to ensure that the predicate succeeds only if the first argument is a list with at least one element.)

If the `append` is successful, then the solution is either `P1` (`P` is unified with `P1`) or a recursive call to `div2` with the remainder of the first argument list with the prefix `P1` absent.

If the `append` fails (which will happen if the number of partition elements `N` is larger than the first argument list length), then `P` is unified with the first argument list.